# Problems while starting, stopping and restarting a thread in c ++

Tags: c++, multithreading

I have just begun working with different threads and am now facing an "infinity" problem. The basic idea is to start a thread for a detector read out and stop it for calibration purposes. Afterwards it should continue.

The following code is a minimal example of what I am trying to do. Windows.h is used for the Sleep function and could be exchanged by anything that delays the example for a short amount of time.

```
// header for ThreadTest
#include <boost/thread.hpp> 
#include <windows.h>
#include <iostream>

class ThreadTest;
void thread(ThreadTest* test);

class ThreadTest {
public:
bool _doWork;
void startTest(){
    _doWork = true;  
    _test = boost::thread(thread,this);
}

void stopTest() {
    _doWork = false;
    _test.join();
};
private:
boost::thread _test;    
};

void thread(ThreadTest* test) {
while (test->_doWork) {
    std::cout << "Working..." << std::endl; 
    Sleep(2000);
}
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
ThreadTest test;
int a=0;

std::cout << "Start Test 1" << std::endl;
test.startTest();

std::cin >> a;

std::cout << "Stop Test 1" << std::endl;
test.stopTest();

std::cout << "Start Test 2" << std::endl;
test.startTest();

std::cin >> a;

std::cout << "Stop Test 2" << std::endl;
test.stopTest();

std::cout << "Start Test 3" << std::endl;
test.startTest();

std::cin >> a;

std::cout << "Stop Test 3" << std::endl;
test.stopTest();

return 0;
}
```

The first time the Thread runs until cin gets some input. Afterwards the program continues without bothering to wait at the second or third cin. Has anyone an idea why this behaviour occurs or how I could prevent it?

Thank you very much in advance for your advice.

Comment: What input do you enter when prompted?

Comment: I am afraid to start C++ holy war, but in such case I just write: `char c; scanf("%c", &c);` Pressing Enter continues execution - much better than C++ streams.

Comment: Also, use `boost::this_thread::sleep(boost::posix_time::milliseconds(2000));` - boost sleep.

Answer (score 0):

What sort of input do you have on `std::cin`?  If it's not
a number (`int`), then `std::cin` will set `failbit`, and all
further input will be a no-op, returning immediately.  If you
just want to wait for the user to do something, using
`std::ignore( std::numeric_limits<streamsize>::max(), '\n' )` is
a good solution; this will wait until the user enters a new
line.

Comment: If you are already including `Windows.h` anyway, another way of properly pausing is the `system("pause");` call

Comment: Your comment about the usage of std::cin helped me a lot, thank you very much. I changed the code from streaming to using std::getline and now my problems are solved.